# Combinatorics on a plane

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Given points on a plane such that the distance between each two of them is not greater than $n$, settle whether there exists such a circle with a diameter of length $n$ such that all of the given points are inside this circle (or on its edge).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Comment: The problem is very hard for me and I don't even know how start the solution... Although for me the answer seems to be 'yes' i have no clue how to show it.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Consider an equilateral triangle with side length of $n$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. The only thing that comes to my mind considering your hint is that I'm able to prove that all given points are inside an equilateral triangle with side length of $2n$. I'm not sure if that's what you meant by your hint because it doesn't 'help' us with the problem...

Comment: This is one configuration of three points that can't be inside of a circle with diameter of length $n$, so you can't always guarantee that such a circle exists.

Comment: I'm not convinced... Can you please extend your way of thinking?

Comment: Ok, after a consideration, I understand my mistake.
Then can you prove that all of the given points are inside a circumcircle of the triangle you mentioned (then its radius would be $\frac{n\cdot \sqrt{3}}{3}$)? :-)

Comment: @TomBarnett Guided by my intuition it shouldn't be possible, but it certainly requires a deepr thought. I will try to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll be thinking about it, too.

Comment: @TomBarnett In fact it can be done. Of course it's enough to prove when the distance is exactly $n$. We have proved that any three points can be included in such a circle. Now if you add any new point it has to be inside the circles with radius $n$, centered at each of the three points. It's not hard to see that the intersection of the three circles is inside the circumcircle

Comment: @TomBarnett Maybe the proof isn't that simple, as if some length is less than $n$, then we have multiple choices for the circumcircle and it might not be easy to decide which one is the optimal.

Comment: Hmm... I think thats it's quite easily provable if three of given points make up an equilateral  triangle. But what if not...?